# Samsung Galaxy Note II slow startup

Tags: boot, samsung-galaxy-note-2

My Galaxy Note II used to statup in 5-6 seconds normally.
But yesterday when i switched on the device after charging it, it took almost 14-15 seconds for my home screen to show up.
I am pretty sure that i didnt install anything new. The device is not rooted.
Is there anyway i can check what might be making the startup slow?

Answer (score 1):

There might be some apps slowing the starup. Autostarts is an app which helps you see what apps run on boot. Unless you have root you'll not be able to make any changes though. It'll just be read only.  See this: [Autostarts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.elsdoerfer.android.autostarts)

Update: [Startup Cleaner 2.0](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bright.startup2) is for unrooted phones. You can now stop an app from loading at startup.

Answer (score 1):

Have you wiped your caches recently, done an update or updated a lot of apps?  It's possible that your phone needed to rebuild the [Dalvik cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29), which would add time to your boot as a one time only thing.  You might have seen a screen saying "Updating Android" on your Note II when that was happening.

If you reboot your phone and the startup time is back to normal, this was most likely the cause.